# Определите тип речевой ошибки

Tags: лексика

В первый месяц жизни дети ходят гулять только на руках.
Обобщена совокупность данных проведенных исследований.
С началом побед на фронтах люди распрямились духом.

Answer (score 1):

1. лексическая несочетаемость слов (ходить на руках)
2. лишнее слово (данных)
3. употребление слова в несвойственном значении (нужно не распрямились, а воспряли духом)